# How can I debug .NET projects on OS X?

Tags: .net, macos, visual-studio, debugging

I use WebStorm on Mac and I have .NET projects. Can I debug this projects on MAC without virtual Windows server? Is it possible?

Comment: *Maybe*.  You can try opening the code in MonoDevelop and see if that works.  The project file probably won't (though the Mono team never ceases to impress me, so you never know) but the code should.  However, the code may have dependencies not provided by Mono.  In that case it *may* (again, depends on a lot of things) make more sense to stick with Visual Studio in a Windows VM.  I've been developing in Visual Studio on a Mac in a Parallels VM for years and enjoy it thoroughly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

.NET is a Microsoft Product. Best to use it, for debuggin, compile, etc, on mac within a Virtual Machine, with MS C# Studio.

For Virtual Machine I suggest VMWare Fusion.

P.S. With release of **dot.net core**, things are changed. Now, there is a Visual Studio for MAC OS, and for Linux.